# High SWR on a new dipole antenna

Tags: swr-meter

I'm constructing / moving a low power fm radio station to a new location. The antenna is a new folded dipole mounted on a 2-3/8" steel pole and attached to a new magnetic base. This location is the top of a 35" high water tank. It is near the edge of the tank and about 4' above the tank surface.  The tx is a Bext XT100 exciter loaded into a interference filter and wired to the dipole with 65' of new LMR 400 line with type -n connectors. I have removed the filter for a test and still have the same condition. My next step will be using a 100 w 50 ohm load to test all points to the antenna.

This station was on a am tower with a monopole in the past and had no issues. I have never worked on a steel structure that is grounded. Is height above the tank an issue? or am I missing something basic.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say how much the SWR was. That could give an indication.

Then, a folded dipole is normally 300 Ohms, unless it's fed in some special way. If both conductors (tubes) are the same diameter, and there's no transformer, and the cable is connected directly to the antenna, then there's your problem. You should have about SWR of 1:6.